# Intermediate state or something similar in vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, state-management

I am trying to get some text to scroll either horizontally , vertically or stay fixed depending on the space the current text needs. If it fits within the container it should stay fixed. If it does not, it should move. I don't know the text in advance and I have dynamic container size.

I am trying to check whether text overflows or not and it works fine out of mounted state for the component. I do this by comparing a combination of scrollheight to clientheight and textcontainer size vs the content container size.

```
<div id="content-container" :class="behaviourBasedClasses(data)">
    <p id="text-container" :style="behaviourBasedTextStyle(data)">{{ text }}</p>
</div>
```

Updating also works as long as the text fits within the container. The problem is switching between animated and non-animated state. The data attribute in the code contains font-size and other attributes to logically decide the classes to use and the textstyles.

What I would need to solve the problem is the ability to get the text back into non-animated state. Then I could just use the routine I use in mounted state each time the text, font-size or container size changes.

states: no-scroll (non-animated):

```
<div id="content-container" class="no-scroll">
    <p id="text-container" style="font-size:100px;">{{ text }}</p>
</div>
```

horizontal-scroll (animated):

```
<div id="content-container" class="scroll-horizontal">
    <p id="text-container">{{ text }} style="font-size:120px; padding-left: 663.065px; position: relative; margin: auto 0px; line-height: 662.985px; animation-name: scroll-horizontal2; animation-duration: 79.4095s; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-iteration-count: infinite;"</p>
</div>
```

If the text is horizontally scrolled the scrollWidth gets really wide and it stays that way whatever change I make to the affecting data. Thus I am unable to get out of scrolling mode.

If I go into devtools and manually edit the markup back to no-scroll state the code works again. But I don't know how to get there programatically.